# undefined method `where' for #<Group:0x8623338>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to find my group by ID and put a where on it(Title in this case. Dates in another case) But it throws the error `undefined method where' for #<Group:0x8623338>`

This is my query:

```
group = Group.find_by_id(params[:group_id]).where(:title => '%titel%')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
group = Group.where(title: '%title%').find_by_id(params[:group_id])
```

The reason you get this error is you can't call 'scope' methods on `ActiveRecord::Base` instance (which is returned by `find_by_id` method). Now, you call `where` on `Group` (which is ok) and then call `find_by_id` on relation returned by `where`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'd like to do the same for my `Activity` model(Activity has group_id and a has_many :through with Clients. The start_date/end_date are in `Activityclient`). Because now it says that Activity.start_date doesn't exist(Because its in `Activityclient`): `@act = Activity.where(:start_date => startdate..startdate + 1.weeks).find_by_group_id(params[:group_id])`

Comment: @CaptainCarl please ask another question, or search for it. It isn't related with this one.

Comment: I'm asking waaayyy too many has_many :through questions lately. Noone either understands them or doesn't bother to answer them. That's why I tried here

Comment: @CaptainCarl If your research fails, please ask on SO anyway and provide link to this question here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
group = Group.where("title like ? AND id =?", '%titel%', params[:group_id])
```